# How to apply corner radius to a UIView without issues?

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, shadow, cornerradius

Currently I'm applying a corner radius and shadow to multiple UIView's in a scrollview. I've noticed that adding a corner radius and shadow makes the scrollview lag like crazy whenever I scroll. How can I apply these affects without having my performance suffer?

Answer (score 1):

Try by setting also the `shadowPath` of the layer:

```
view.layer.cornerRadius=6.0f;
view.layer.borderWidth=2.0f;
view.layer.borderColor=[UIColor grayColor].CGColor;
view.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
view.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.3f;
view.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 0.0f);
view.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:view.bounds];
view.layer.shadowPath = path.CGPath;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
+(UIImage *)makeRoundCornerImage : (UIImage*) img : (int) cornerWidth : (int) cornerHeight
{
    UIImage * newImage = nil;

    if( nil != img)
    {
        NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
        int w = img.size.width;
        int h = img.size.height;

        CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
        CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, w, h, 8, 4 * w, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);

        CGContextBeginPath(context);
        CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, img.size.width, img.size.height);
        addRoundedRectToPath(context, rect, cornerWidth, cornerHeight);
        CGContextClosePath(context);
        CGContextClip(context);

        CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, w, h), img.CGImage);

        CGImageRef imageMasked = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
        CGContextRelease(context);
        CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
        [img release];


        newImage = [[UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageMasked] retain];
        CGImageRelease(imageMasked);

        [pool release];
    }

    return newImage;
}
```

//  With the help of  This method we can  create the round corner of any PNG file

```
 UIImage *imageFromFile = [UIImage imageNamed:@"FilterFields.png"];
        imageFromFile = [ImageManipulator
makeRoundCornerImage:imageFromFile : 10 : 10];


        [SmallTable setImage:imageFromFile];
```